# Add array data to in vue without loosing old data

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

i am making vue application i want to add more data which is fetching through laravel return in array without loosing old data

my methods is

```
    getData () {
        axios.get('get/users')
            .then(response => {
                this.queue = response.data.users
            })
        .catch(e => {
          this.errors.push(e)
        })
    }
```

and my data

```
    data: function () {
        return {
            queue: []
        }
    },
```

Full Script is

```
  data: function () {
        return {
            queue: []
        }
    },

  created () {
    this.getData()
  },
  methods: {


    getData () {
        axios.get('get/users')
            .then(response => {
                this.queue = response.data.users
            })
        .catch(e => {
          this.errors.push(e)
        })
    },

    decide (choice) {
      this.$refs.tinder.decide(choice)
    },

    submit (choice) {
      switch (choice) {
        case 'nope': // 左滑
          break;
        case 'like': // 右滑
          break;
        case 'super': // 上滑
          break;
      }
      if (this.queue.length < 2) {
        this.getData()
      }
    }
  }
```

here is video link

https://youtu.be/iv82EGMD4XA

i want when queue have 2 data left trigger this.getData()
fetch users and add array data to queue without loosing old queue data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [concat function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```
this.queue = this.queue.concat(response.data.users);
```

In the axios response

Instead of the

```
this.queue = response.data.users
```

Comment: Would the reactivity kick in in this case? The array ref never changes and elements are added to the array so it may not be detected as a change. I think it would make better sense to use it like `this.queue = this.queue.concat(response.data.users);` `concat` is listed as a `non-mutating` method in [the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods)